# Qt C++ QTcpServer not connecting to Threaded Socket

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I have worked through `C++ Qt 68 - QTcpServer using multiple threads` and followed his steps, but I can't seem to get the program to work correctly.
I am using Qt 6.3.0 and the only difference between VoidRealm's code and mine is that I am using the new `Signals and Slots` system.
My Code:

```cpp
//myserver.h

#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mythread.h"

class MyServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void startServer();

protected:
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);
};

#endif // MYSERVER_H
```

```cpp
//myserver.cpp
#include "myserver.h"

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent)
    : QTcpServer{parent}
{
}

void MyServer::startServer()
{
    if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not start Server!";
    } 
    else 
    {
        qDebug() << "Listening...";
    }
}

void MyServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connectng...";
    MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);

    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);

    thread->start();

}
```

```cpp
//mythread.h

#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread(int ID, QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void run();
    void readyRead();
    void disconnected();

signals:
    void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketError);

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    int socketDescriptor;
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

```cpp
//mythread.cpp

#include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread(int ID, QObject *parent)
    :QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    qDebug() <<socketDescriptor << " Starting Thread";
    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
    {
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socket, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &MyThread::readyRead,Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &MyThread::disconnected,Qt::DirectConnection);

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client Connected!";

    exec();
}

void MyThread::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Data in: " << Data;

    socket->write(Data);
}

void MyThread::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";

    socket->deleteLater();

    quit();
}
```

When Running this, I get the console saying `Listening...`, but when I then use command prompt and change it to telnet using `...> telnet`, and then type `...> open 127.0.0.1 1234`, all I am getting is:

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'

Microsoft Telnet> open 127.0.0.1 1234
Connecting To 127.0.0.1...
```

After which nothing happens. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you find out when you debugged it?  Is 'incomingConnection()' called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. The `int` in the `incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)` should have been a `qintptr`, making it `incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)`

The program works now.